# asp.net core database ms sql and postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, asp.net-core

I want to set a database for development environment and production but the database provider are different.
The dev environment is pointed to appsettings.development.json and for production is appsettings.json.
I would like to use MS Sql server (localDb) on dev environment and postgresql on production.
How could i achieve that?

Comment: Don't do that. Use the same DBMS for development as you using in production. Especially if they are so different like Postgres and SQL Server

Comment: If you use different DBMS on production how can you ever test your code???

Comment: I know that it's not ideal to do that. I just would like to know if it's possible. Just setting up startup to use both databases but choose the right connection string according environment.